# asp.net unable to retrieve metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

hi i am having a issue with MVC to make a controller even after reading the tips.
adding a constructor on the DbContext, deleting the  non worked, changing providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" and so on.

my model class look like this:

```
public class RecruiterModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string CompanySize { get; set; }
    public string LinkedInCompanyURL { get; set; }
    public string LinkedInID { get; set; }
    public string Specialities { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int ContactPhone { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
}

public class RecruiterDBContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<RecruiterModel> Recruiters { get; set; }
}
```

and my web.config connectionStrings looks like this:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated  Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="RecruiterDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Recruiters.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to you `Recruiter` class:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Or apply the `Key` attribute to one of you existing properties. For example:

```
[Key]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

on MSDN, you have the [Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) topic:

> **Primary Key Convention**
>
> Code First infers that a property is a primary key if a property on a
>   class is named “ID” (not case sensitive), or the class name followed
>   by "ID". If the type of the primary key property is numeric or GUID it
>   will be configured as an identity column.
>
> ```
> public class Department
> {
>     // Primary key
>     public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
>
>     . . .    
>
> }
> ```

Another reference on the topic is made in this [Code First DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx) article:

> Key
>
> Entity Framework relies on every entity having a key value (aka
>   EntityKey) that it uses for tracking entities. One of the conventions
>   that code first depends on is how it implies which property is the key
>   in each of the code first classes. That convention is **to look for a
>   property named “Id” or one that combines the class name and “Id”, such
>   as “BlogId”**. In addition to EF’s use of the EntityKey, the property
>   will map to a primary key column in the database.

Comment: Hi Alex, I still get the same error after trying that solution and the full error is:

Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Recruiter.Models.RecruiterModel'.
Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

Comment: If you are using SQLExpress, modify your connection string: `connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated  Security=SSPI;"`.

Comment: I just tried that and I still get the same error, I am trying to follow the project idea from ASP.net movie project exmaple.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model

Comment: I have found the solution to create the controller class:

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to create the controller class:
On the model class i added the

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class RecruiterModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set;

then on the web.config i commented out the whole

connectionStrings tag

then i created the controller but and it worked.

thanks gos out to Alex Filipovici and Young Yang - MSFT on:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1888573.aspx/1?Unable+to+retrieve+metadata+for+when+trying+to+create+a+controller

though it works but on the Solution Explorer tab under App_Data i do not see the db file... hmm another issue.