# The entity type Order is not part of the model for the current context when creating a create, edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am adding a create view ( which I have done many times in the project) but I am getting the following error when I try to create the view:

> The entity type Order is not part of the model for the current context.

I can not figure out what I am missing? Let me know if I need to post more info.

```
public ActionResult CreateOrder()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateLoanOrder(Order newOrder)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Orders.Add(newOrder);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Orders");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(newOrder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What object is your View expecting as its Model? When/where is the error appearing?

Comment: This is happening when I click create - to create a new DB record. Orders object.

I tried to delete and recreate the create page and I get: There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Intranet.Models.Order.' Could not find the CLR type for Orders.Order

Comment: What version of EF are you using? The metadata error sounds like the entities are messed up somewhere. Have you looked at this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238811)